# In app purchase testing in alpha mode it is possible?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

It is compulsory for checking inappbilling to original publish mode if no than if i set apk in alphatest mode than after how many hours i can check my inappbilling  with same code running from eclipse.

I have tried with publish apk in original mode and than check it is work but if i want any change than again i am waiting fo 5 to 6 hour for new apk with change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can test in-app purchase without publishing the app. and also you can't check in-app billing running code from eclipse. it will give you an error code =3;
which means error_not_Market managed. To check it you have to download the app from app store and run.you may use the log cat to get the response. so don't forget to put necessary logs in your application.

Comment: but every time i need to wait for 5 to 6 hours is there any other solutions

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Implement the LicenseCheckerCallback  and 
if you are getting the error code 3, ie ERROR_NOT_MARKETMANGED, just for testing think that you have successed and call the function allow() from there. Ie if(errorCode==3){ allow(int reason)}and int the implementation of the function allow() write the code for success.

don't forget to remove this before publishing.